# Replace a substring in bash v3?

Tags: bash

I am running bash v3 script within a pipeline and facing an issue where string data is not correctly replaced to another substring.

`$f` is a .tgz file and I have extracted the name of the file to `checkVersion`

```
checkVersion=${f##*/}

checkVersion=$(echo $checkVersion | sed -r 's/[*]{3}/react/g') # change '***' -> 'react'

if [[ $package == *"@reactframework"* ]]; then # matches "reactframework"
    package=$(echo $package | sed 's/-/\/''/1') #changes the first dash
else # matches react-framework
    package=$(echo $package | sed 's/-/\/''/2') # changes the second dash

checkVersion=$(echo $checkVersion | sed -E 's/-([0-9])/@\1/') # change the last char before the first digit to "@"


echo $changeVersion # as of now "***" is not correctly replaced to "react" and stays the same
```

`checkVersion=$(echo $checkVersion | sed -r 's/[*]{3}/react/g')` this command runs correctly in local environment but seems to not work in pipeline.

Comment: Are you using [strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/)? It will help you diagnose the "seems not to work" more precisely.

Comment: Why not use the bash operator? `checkVersion=${checkVersion//\*\*\*/react}`

Comment: You should quote the variable: `echo "$checkVersion"`. Otherwise, wildcards will be expanded in it.

Comment: When you're trying to debug a script, put `set -x` at the beginning to see a trace of execution.

Comment: Also use shellcheck.net, it will warn you about problems like not quoting variables.

Comment: @Thomas that "strict mode" link suggests using `set -e` which is contrary to the advice in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105. It also suggests setting IFS to a value which works around the problems described in that article which only occur because they aren't quoting their variables properly so that's bad advice vs just "quote your variables".

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I didn't know about that. The most useful is `-o pipefail` then, which might help OP here.